# Passing nothing to an AsyncTask in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How do I instantiate and call and class extending AsyncTask if I am passing nothing to it?

Also, I am setting a textview in the UI to the calculated result.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 32):

Example implementation for Async without params and result Bitmap in onPostExecute result

```
/**
 * My Async Implementation without doInBackground params
 * 
 */
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Bitmap bitmap;

        .... 

        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        ....
    }
}
```

In your activity, you should to add this implementation:

```
MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myAsyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: while calling myAsyncTask.execute, isn't it necessary to supply the parameters??

Comment: Yes. On that case the function can be executed without parameters. If you need more information please contact me.

Answer (score 11):

I think what you meant to ask was how do I write an AsyncTask that doesn't ask for any parameters. The trick is to define what you expect to use as parameter and return value in the extension of your class:
`class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` for example doesn't expect any parameters and doesn't return any either.
`AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>` expects a String (or multiple strings) and returns a Drawable (from its own `doInBackground` method to its own `onPostExecute` method)

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I need to set some text on a custom view i built, (no parameters set or returned) but how do i do that?

Comment: You can create a constructor in the AsyncTask class in which you pass a reference to the view. If you save that in a variable in the class you can use that variable to set some text to it in the `onPostExecute` method. Be sure to set the text in `onPostExecute` though, because Android doesn't allow you to change the UI in a nonUI thread (your AsyncTask), except when you do it in `onPostExecute`